# Does my node server need to manually end the response before the function ends?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node server and I'm using express to process POST requests to it. My question is, do I have to call response.end() before my processing function ends or will that happen automatically?

Why I'm asking is because my server works as expected for the first few requests, then it starts throwing "request timeout" errors, so I'm trying to track down the issue.

I should also note that I always send something in the response using response.send() if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ending of the response is handled automatically. If you were using the native HTTP module, you should always end server responses. But since you're using Express, the response end is automatically handled for you.

```
this.end(head ? null : body);
```

You can find Express' response logic [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L154).