# Why does Express not call response.end() for me in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I have read this question and the answer to it ([Does my node server need to manually end the response before the function ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796774/does-my-node-server-need-to-manually-end-the-response-before-the-function-ends)), and don't think it answered my question.

I am using express and using the following code to send the result to client (with RESTful API):

```
res.status(400);
res.write('Verification failed.');
res.end(); // why express cannot add it for me, so that I do NOT need to repeat this line
```

I have a C++/Java/C# background. In these languages, there is a principle that closing method should be called by who opened it, e.g. stream, file, pointers, etc. Is it not possilbe or are there other concerns?

EDIT:

1. Make the comments more clear that the code works actually and I just do not want to repeat the res.end();
2. I know that there is a short cut as `res.send()`. The question is why should I care about the difference between `write` and `send`, and the middleware would not handle it for me. For example, in Spring MVC, you do not need to `end` or `close` your `HttpResponse` by yourself.

Comment: I saw some good answers below, but would appreciate if you could compare it with Spring MVC or other implementation in C++, Java or C# regarding the design principle behind.

Answer (score 0):

In express you would do something like this as a shortcut:

```
res.send(400, 'Verification failed.');
```

Though I don't know why your code doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

because when you are working with streams/sockets the middleware wont know when to end your response. this is why you use

```
res.send
```

or call

```
res.end
```

after your stream write is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a middleware that does this for you that would be placed at the end of your middleware/routing stack, but then you'd still have to write `next();` for execution to get there.

At least you can combine `write()` and `end()` into one step in node core with `end('Verification failed');` (Express adds `send()` as previously mentioned though).